# How to write a recursive method to generate an arithmetic sequence when object has only final fields?

Tags: java, recursion

So I'm working through my first ever CS class, so my experience is definitely on the low end, but for an assignment I have to make a method to generate and return the number of index n in the arithmetic sequence with start value init and common difference diff.

This is super easy to do without using recursion at all, but recursion is required. I am also limited to what fields, methods and method signatures I can use.

I also understand how to make this method using the code below.

```
public class ArithmeticNumberGenerator implements NumberGenerator {
    private int init; // first term in the sequence
    private final int diff; // common difference

    /**
     * Constructs an arithmetic number generator with given
     * start value init and common difference diff
     * @param init start value
     * @param diff common difference
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if any of the input arguments
     * is illegal
     */
    public ArithmeticNumberGenerator(int init, int diff) throws 
IllegalArgumentException {
        if (init < 0 || diff < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot use negative numbers.");
        else {
            this.init = init;
            this.diff = diff;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int generateNumber(int n) {
        // Time Complexity: O(?)
        // This method generates the number of index n
        // in an arithmetic sequence recursively

        if (n == 0)
            return init;
        else {
            init = init + diff;
            return generateNumber(n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

However, for the assignment, the "init" field is supposed to be final, and I can not figure out how to implement this method when that is the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the recursive definition of an arithmetic sequence? See for example https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/sequences/constructing-arithmetic-sequences/a/writing-recursive-formulas-for-arithmetic-sequences. This is very straightforward if you understand recursive formulas. You can translate it to code literally.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I understand that and I believe that is exactly what I am doing in the above code, however I'm not sure how to edit the above code for the case where init is final, since the line "init = init + diff;" would yield an error in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you must use recursion, and all the method signatures above are fixed, and `init` must be final.  The following obeys those rules.

```
public static class ArithmeticNumberGenerator implements NumberGenerator {

    private final int init; // first term in the sequence
    private final int diff; // common difference
    /**
     * Constructs an arithmetic number generator with given start value init
     * and common difference diff
     * 
     * @param init
     *            start value
     * @param diff
     *            common difference
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if any of the input arguments is illegal
     */
    public ArithmeticNumberGenerator(int init, int diff) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (init < 0 || diff < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot use negative numbers.");
        else {
            this.init = init;
            this.diff = diff;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int generateNumber(int n) {
        // Time Complexity: O(?)
        // This method generates the number of index n
        // in an arithmetic sequence recursively

        if (n == 0)
            return init;
        else {
            ArithmeticNumberGenerator g = new ArithmeticNumberGenerator(init+diff, diff);
            return g.generateNumber(n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! That was my first thought too, but the description given in the assignment leads me to believe we are also not allowed to have any other fields than the init and diff fields.

Comment: Are you allowed to change `generateNumber(int n)` to `generateNumber(int n, int sum)`?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately the method signatures cannot be changed, constructors cannot be overriden, etc. They gave us a template to use and we are only allowed to edit what is in the generateNumber method and the constructor.

Comment: Ah yes! That should work! I was initially a little leery of making a new object within the recursive method but I didn't really have a solid reasoning for why not to. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think there is any other way to solve this.  This is not a 'normal' way to use recursion, but given the unusual constraints it seems the only way.